# How to define custom Object name for instance of created class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Python everything is object. We do find the name of the object we are using type() builtin method.

If I create class as follows

```
class Sample:

      pass

a=Sample()

type(a)

returns as __main__.Sample
```

Here  I want it to be print the name of object of my choice, how do I do that.

```
Ex: type({})

return Dict
```

I want to name object instance of my custom class

Answer (score 0):

One can use **module** to replace **main** in type of the class instance,

i.e

```
class Sample():
    __module__='custom'
```

type(Sample())  returns custom.Sample

Answer (score 0):

```
I think I figured it out with existing python packages,

i.e

in pandas, it has DataFrame class or object when you define variable to this object and type of it returns pandas.core.frame.DataFrame. Here DataFrame is the class and pandas.core.frame is the module name of the class

so one can define his object name with replacing __main__ only i.e as shown below

class Sample():

       __module__='Custom'

a=Sample()

print(type(a))

prints==> < class Custom.Sample>
```